# PHP newline after 10th comma

Tags: php

I need to split the following string:

```
333 ,351 ,359 ,360 ,370 ,371 ,385 ,492 ,512 ,514 ,528 ,539 ,546 ,628 ,630 ,634 ,636 ,702 ,706 ,709 ,710 ,715 ,718 ,719 ,763 ,770 ,803 ,822 ,823
```

into separate lines where a new line begins after the last 10th comma, if that makes any sense?

So it looks like this:

```
333 ,351 ,359 ,360 ,370 ,371 ,385 ,492 ,512 ,514 ,

528 ,539 ,546 ,628 ,630 ,634 ,636 ,702 ,706 ,709 ,

710 ,715 ,718 ,719 ,763 ,770 ,803 ,822 ,823
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: explode to an array on `,`; array_chunk into blocks of 10, walk the array imploding on `,` again, display each array element with a newline.... `$result = array_map(function($value) { return implode(',', $value); }, array_chunk(explode(',', $data), 10));

foreach($result as $line) { echo $line, PHP_EOL; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the comments for explanation:-

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); // check if any error occur
    ini_set('display_errors',1); // display error
    $string = '333 ,351 ,359 ,360 ,370 ,371 ,385 ,492 ,512 ,514 ,528 ,539 ,546 ,628 ,630 ,634 ,636 ,702 ,706 ,709 ,710 ,715 ,718 ,719 ,763 ,770 ,803 ,822 ,823'; // original string
    echo $string; // echo original string
    $array = explode(',',$string); // explode string with comma to make it array
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($array); // print array
    $chunked_array = array_chunk($array,10); // chunk array to each 10 counts and make a multidimensional array
    $new_string = ''; // create a new empty string
    foreach ($chunked_array as $chunked_ar){ // iterate through multi-dimensional array 

      $new_string .= implode(',',$chunked_ar)."\n"; // convert each array to string and add new line and assign it to new string variable
    }
    echo $new_string; // echo new variable.
  ?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/557389

Note :  Adding error_reporting code (first two lines after `<?php`) is always a very good practice to find out errors and resolve them. Thanks.

Comment: This one worked a treat! many thanks for your detailed answer! very informative!

Comment: can anyone tell why -ve marked. even it is correct?

Comment: @A.L  Note written to tell that error reporting  will always help to programmers in the context of facing errors. `Thanks` is just for showing gratitude to check and mark the code as accepted answer.

Comment: Also peoples who ever down-voted. please give the reason also, so that other will come to know what he have to improve. thanks.

Comment: My question was not about the error reporting but the `:-` characters, to my knowledge, colons usually have a space after, not a minus.

Comment: @A.L No any specific reason to wrote `:-`. usually i am habituated to that. Sorry if it seems ambiguous to you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $string is that previous string of yours:

```
<?php

$myArray = explode(",", $string);
$newString = "";
$count = 0;
foreach ($myArray as $value)
{
  $newString = $newString.$value.",";
  $count++;
  if ($count==10)
  {
    $count=0;
    $newString = $newString."\n";
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do that...

```
$str = '333 ,351 ,359 ,360 ,370 ,371 ,385 ,492 ,512 ,514 ,528 ,539 ,546 ,628 ,630 ,634 ,636 ,702 ,706 ,709 ,710 ,715 ,718 ,719 ,763 ,770 ,803 ,822 ,823';

$iCount = 0;
foreach (explode(',',$str) as $iNum)
    echo $iNum.' ,'.(++$iCount % 10 == 0 ? '<br>' : '');
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not doing the trick: I'm getting the following:
333,,
351,,
359,,
360,,
370,,
371,,
385,,
492,,
512,,
514,, i'm getting a linebreak on each number using the following code:   $str = $row['Reference'] . ',';


$iCount = 0;
foreach (explode(',',$str) as $iNum) {
    if ($iCount % 10 == 0)
        echo '<br>';

    echo $iNum.',';
    $iCount++;
} `

Comment: odd, I did test this!  the explode removes the commas and then they are re added as each item is output... never mind anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with one-liner.

```
preg_replace('/((.*?,){10})/', "$1\n", $text);
```